Teleport | Composable - Using component inside of composable and render via Teleport
On my Vue3 app, we have a 'BaseModal' component that does the basic stuff a modal would do (open, close, etc), but we're looking to clean up some of the cumbersome code.
We were hoping to programmatically add the modal to the UI via a composable function:
import { h, Teleport } from 'vue'
import BaseModal from '@shared/components/BaseModal.vue'

export default function useModal({ to = 'body' } = {}) {
  const show = (props = {}, slots = {}) => {
    h(Teleport, { to }, h(BaseModal, { ...props }, { ...slots }))
  }

  return { show }
}

Potential usage:
const { show } = useModal()

show({ title: 'Foobar' })

Unfortunately, this doesn't work at all. Am I using Teleport incorrectly? Potential workarounds?

VUE SFC PLAYGROUND

A render function is a function that returns vnodes. You return nothing
The vnodes returned should be mounted, there's no parent component to mount to
So you should mount manually
Make sure properly unmount the dialog
Return exposed methods of the component so it could be manipulated by the client code further

Parent.vue
<script setup>

import Foobar from './Foobar.vue';
  
import {ref, h, reactive} from 'vue';
import useModal from './useModal';

window.console.log = msg => log.push(msg);
const log = reactive([]);

const { show } = useModal();
const modal = ref();

const content = {default: () => h(Foobar)};

</script>

<template>
  <div class="buttons">
  <button @click="modal = show({ title: 'Foobar' }, content)">Show Foobar</button>
  <button @click="modal = show({ title: 'Bazfoo' }, content)">Show Bazfoo</button>
  <button @click="modal?.close()">Close opened dialog</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div v-for="msg in log">{{ msg }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

useModal.js
import { h, render, ref, getCurrentInstance, onUnmounted } from 'vue'
import BaseModal from './BaseModal.vue'

export default function useModal({ to = 'body' } = {}) {
  
  const self = getCurrentInstance();
  const exposed = ref();
  const close = () => (exposed.value = null, render(null, document.querySelector(to)));
  
  onUnmounted(close);

  const show = (props = {}, slots = {}) => {
    const vnode = h(BaseModal, {...props, onClose:close}, {...slots});
    vnode.key = Math.random();
    vnode.appContext = self.appContext;
    render(vnode, document.querySelector(to));
    exposed.value = vnode.component.exposed;
    return exposed;
  }
  return { show }
}

BaseModal.vue
<script setup>
import {ref, onUnmounted} from 'vue';
const props = defineProps({
  title: String
});
const $dialog = ref();
onUnmounted(() => console.log(props.title + ' closed!'));
defineExpose({
  close: () => $dialog.value.close()
})
</script>

<template>
  <dialog open ref="$dialog" style="max-width:300px">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <p><slot/></p>
    <button @click="$dialog.close()">Close</button>
  </dialog>
</template>


@kissu what sense in adding html and js to code? i see that the format is recognized automatically

Not really. Give it a second look. It's far more readable this way because matches something very close to VueJS highlighting. You can always rollback if not happy or highlight this way by default so that I don't need to do it myself after you.

Why can't I find any documentation on the 'render' export you used here? Whenever I search for the render function it returns the h() function.

@RizaKhan yes, there're some public functions of Vue still being not documented , i'd added 2 issues to add something to the docs...

@RizaKhan i'd expect an upvote also for such extensive efforts to help you
